# Пройтись по JSON массиву с категориями с произвольным уровнем вложенности подкатегорий

Tags: java, android, json, рекурсия

Здравствуйте, прошу вашей помощи. Может немного не понятно озаглавил вопрос, ситуация следующая. Есть JSONArray [Ссылка на массив](https://money.yandex.ru/api/categories-list) в нем список категорий, у каждой категории есть (или нет) список подкатегорий в виде вложенного массива. Как пройтись по этому массиву и вернуть в коллекцию каждый JSONObject? Желательно с информацией о родительской категории? Пробую рекурсией, но сижу уже третий день и безрезультатно. Очень нужна помощь, есть азарт разобраться, а понимания ситуации нет.

Пока имею вот такой код, подскажите, чего я тут напорол не правильного?

```
private static JSONObject getJSONObject(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject tmpObj = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (null != tmpObj.optJSONArray("subs")) {
            jsonObject = getJSONObject(tmpObj.optJSONArray("subs"));
            break;
        } else {
            jsonObject = tmpObj;
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: Что означает "вернуть в коллекцию **каждый** JSONObject", вас интересует [итератор](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) или вы хотите вернуть список всех объектов?

Comment: мне нужно вернуть список всех объектов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ну я не гуру JSON но я бы наверно сделал так, с помощью Object.keys(JSON).length проверял бы длину, если она больше 1 значит это вложенное значение, если 1 то это пара ключ-значение, и проходил бы весь JSON шаг за шагом с помощью того-же Object.keys(JSON) , забирая значения так-же JSON(Object.keys(JSON)[i]) . на вскидку как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш JSON по заданию вовсе не список - там дерево! Посему есть два варианта:

1. **Делать для хранения список-Декоратор** (когда внутри каждого элемента хранится массив таких же элементов как он сам),

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<Item> listChildren;
}
```

Писать рекурсивный парсер обхода этого дерева для считывания в коллекцию и еще один для записи из коллекции.

2. **Использовать стандартное решение.** Например Jackson и Tree Model. Он сам соберет дерево напрямую из потока (JSON даже в строку можно не не писать).

Хотя первый вариант познавательнее и веселее он, разумеется, будет падать при изменении структуры входного JSON, магнитных бурь и пятен на солнце.

Comment: Можно ли использовать GSON, а еще лучше Retrofit? У меня проблемы со сборкой проекта при добавление Jackson, как зависимости. Времени разбираться уже нет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вернуть список его надо где-то создать. Или просто передать:

```
private static void getJSONObject(ArrayList<JSONObject> list, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject tmpObj = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (null != tmpObj.optJSONArray("subs")) {
            getJSONObject(list, tmpObj.optJSONArray("subs"));
            break;
        } else {
            list.add(tmpObj);
        }
    }
}
```

ЗЫ Ответ может быть не полным, ждем уточнений, так или не так...